# UITableView - custom unused cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

If my table view is 480 in height for example, and for some reason I only end up with 2 or 3 cells, the rest below are displayed in the typical white with the light gray dividers. How can I fill those unused cells with a custom image? I know I can change the background color of the table, but I actually want to fill each unused cell with an image instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do exactly what you said: fill each unused cell with an image.

basically you'll need to do your logic in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to calculate how many "fake cells" you'll need and then return them in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the dividers (set the table's cell divider style to none) and set the background to transparent, then add a UIImageView with your background to the background.

If you really want an image per cell, then you will need to calculate the number of extra cells needed and return them from numberOfRowsInSection, then render the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.